# How can I draw this network of tubes in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, networking, drawing

[image]

I have a distribution of tube radius `r`, and I would like to plot tubes for all the sampled `r` in single figure as shown in the figure above. The tubes have following characteristics:

- The length of all tubes is constant, but radius is varying.
- The narrowest tube will be completely filled
  with light gray color.
- The length of the light gray color from bottom in all other tubes is
  inversely proportional to the radius of the tube i.e.

  `length of light grey color from bottom = constant/r`
- The remaining length of the tube will be filled with dark gray color.
- Magnitudes of `r` and total length of each tube is of the order of `1e-005`m and `1e-002` m, respectively, so they need to be standardized compared to the X and Y axes units.
- The white interspaces are just spaces and not tubes.

**UPDATE (Based on the answer by Boris)**

This is the code from Boris in which I made certain changes based on the characteristics of the tubes that I have described above. I am having scaling issues as I am not able to visualize my network of tubes as clearly as can be seen in the figure above.

```
function drawGrayTube (x, r, sigma_wn, theta, del_rho, rmin, rmax,L)
% sigma_wn is in N/m (=Kg/s^2), theta is in degrees, del_rho is in Kg/m^3
% and L is in m
h=((2*sigma_wn*cos((pi/180)*theta))./(del_rho*9.81.*r));
hmin=((2*sigma_wn*cos((pi/180)*theta))./(del_rho*9.81.*rmax));
hmax=((2*sigma_wn*cos((pi/180)*theta))./(del_rho*9.81.*rmin));

rectangle ('Position',[x,0,r/rmax,h], 'FaceColor',[0.7,0.7,0.7]);
ylim([0 1]);

if L>h
    rectangle ('Position',[x,L,r/rmax,L-h], 'FaceColor',[0.3,0.3,0.3]);
    ylim([0 1]);
else
    rectangle ('Position',[x,L,r/rmax,L], 'FaceColor',[0.3,0.3,0.3]);
    ylim([0 1]);
end

end
```

Comment: I would recommend learning how to draw [patches](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/patch.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple function to draw the gray tubes could be for instance

```
function drawGrayTube (x, w, h)
    rectangle ('Position',[x,0,w,h], 'FaceColor',[0.7,0.7,0.7]);
    rectangle ('Position',[x,h,w,100-h], 'FaceColor',[0.3,0.3,0.3]);
end
```

Hereby, `x` is the x position of the tube, `w` denotes the width and `h` between `0` and `100` the height of the light gray part of the tube.

You can now use it in your example by calling

```
drawGrayTube (x, r, 100*constant/r)
```

where you have to adapt the constant such that `constant/r` is at most `1`.

You can write a similar function for the white interspaces.

Assume that you have given a vector of radii (already scaled such that the values are between 0 and 1), e.g., `r=[0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 0.1, 0.5, 0.01]` then on possibility to draw the tubes is

```
interspace = 0.5;
for i=1:length(r)
    drawGrayTube(sum(r(1:i-1))+i*interspace, 100*r(i)+1e-10, r(i)+1e-10); 
end
```

Comment: Boris: Thanks. Assuming we have a distribution of `r`, how do we superimpose all the tubes for all the sampled `r` together on a single figure as shown? Ignore the white interspaces as those are not tubes.

Comment: Even though I am giving both `w` and `h` greater than `0`, yet I get an error that says: `??? Error using ==> rectangle
Width and height must be > 0`

Comment: Your code still doesn't includes all the characteristics that I listed in bullet points in the question. I think it's sort of OK, but I am having scaling issues because I cannot visualize my network of tubes as clearly as in the above figure. Can you take a look at my code above and if you can make changes to it such that I am able to view the tube's width clearly and also the colors' height.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the function `rectangle`